# How to disable ancher tag of HTML by getting child div id

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I have code as below:

```
<a onmouseup="some operation" class="buttonBarButtonContainer" title="">
<div name="buttonBarButton_Save" id="manualDeductionSaveButtonDisable" class="buttonBarButton">
    <table style="height:20px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td nowrap="true">
                    <button class="noTransformButton ico_tb-save"></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

here I have only the div id and I want to disable the parent anchor tag. How can I do? I can only use javascript, not even jquery?

Answer (score 2):

Use parentElement.removeAttribute('onmouseup') as per the code below.  Be sure to put the javascript at the **bottom** of the page (I changed "some operation" to an alert so that you can comment out the javascript to verify it disables the anchor alert when uncommented):

```html
<a onmouseup="alert('hi');" class="buttonBarButtonContainer" title="">
    <div name="buttonBarButton_Save" id="manualDeductionSaveButtonDisable" class="buttonBarButton">
        <table style="height:20px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td nowrap="true">
                        <button class="noTransformButton ico_tb-save">Test</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("manualDeductionSaveButtonDisable").parentElement.removeAttribute('onmouseup');
</script>
```

Comment: It's nice and working for me. Thank you very much. :)